# Sidekiq jobs are getting Enqueued but it's not getting processed. All Jobs are stuck in Enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am trying to send email using `sidekiq` but it's not working. Here is how i setup `sidekiq` with `ActiveJob`

Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

then i run `bundle install`.

Application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = Rails.env
```

UserMailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def activation_needed_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = activate_user_url(@user.activation_token)
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My website')
  end
end
```

UsersController

```
def create
    ...
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.activation_needed_email(@user).deliver_later # this is were i am sending email.
    end
    ...
end
```

Rails Server Log

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: e61df8eb-c6c1-417a-af59-d55fdc13ec98) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "activation_needed_email", "deliver_now", {:args=>[#<GlobalID:0x00007fabff6a3c60 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://jobs-in-nepal/User/83c17355-db86-4ca1-b674-a97fde512592>>]}
```

According to above log file ActiveJob has Enqueued the job, but it's using `deliver_now` rather than `deliver_later`.

I am not receiving any email in my mailbox. When i visit `localhost:3000/sidekiq` then I can see that job is enqueued but job is not processed. How can i process the stuck jobs from enqueued?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the problem by deleting following line from `application.rb`

```
config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = Rails.env
```

looks like sidekiq was getting confused with queue name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting following line from `application.rb`

```
config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = Rails.env
```

and then starting sidekiq by `sidekiq -q mailers`

looks like sidekiq was getting confused with queue name.

Comment: Odd.  This is the only thing that worked for me as well, but no idea why.  If the sidekiq is started properly with config file (e.g.: `sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`) which specifies the queues, there should be a way to override the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell sidekiq which queues to process. By default, some frameworks have their own queue names.

Create a sidekiq configuration file (e. g. `config/sidekiq.yml`) and define the queues that it should use

```
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 2
:max_retries: 3
:timeout: 10

:queues:
  # The default queue for all application jobs that don't have a specific queue.
  - default

  # The default queue for ActionMailer classes.
  - mailers

  # ActionMailbox queues. See `ActionMailbox.queues`.
  - action_mailbox_routing
  - action_mailbox_incineration

  # ActiveStorage queues. See `ActiveStorage.queues`.
  - active_storage_analysis
  - active_storage_purge
```

Then start sidekiq with the configuration: `sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

Comment: I added `sidekiq.yml` file but I sill have same problem. `Create` action is still taking more than 5 seconds to finish. and job is still stuck in Enqueued but not processed. But some how I still receive the email in my mailbox.

Comment: Did you `include Sidekiq::Worker` in active job?

Comment: no I have not `include Sidekiq::Worker` in active job. How to `include Sidekiq::Worker` in active job ? Do i need to create new worker ? if yes then what will my `perform` method looks like?

Comment: Just put it e.g. into your `ApplicationJob`. Not sure if that helps as I never had that problem of yours but my setup with the config from above plus the inclusion of Sidekiq::Worker does what it should.

Comment: You cannot include `Sidekiq::Worker` into `ApplicationJob`